# Block background color not appearing on site

Tags: block-editor

I added custom colors to my `functions.php` file:

```
functions.php
add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
    array(
        'name'  => __( 'Blue'),
        'slug'  => 'blue',
        'color' => '#00548F',
    ),
```

viewing the source in editor:

```
"backgroundColor\":\"blue\"...
<div class=\"wp-block-columns alignfull event-block has-blue-background-color has-background\">
```

and finally in the page inspector:

```
<div class="wp-block-columns alignfull event-block has-blue-background-color has-background">
```

Not surprisingly, the Rules or Computed Values show zero background attributes.

I tried it in another of my themes (both are hand-rolled) and the same result. When I loaded up the twenty-nineteen theme, it worked.

Is there some function, callback, file that is needed to make this work that I might have errantly deletely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're adding theme support for `editor-color-palette` then you need to add styles for those colours to your stylesheet. [As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-support/#block-color-palettes):

> Themes are responsible for creating the classes that apply the colors
> in different contexts. Core blocks use “color” and “background-color”
> contexts. So to correctly apply “strong magenta” to all contexts of
> core blocks a theme should implement the following classes:
>
> ```
> .has-strong-magenta-background-color {
>     background-color: #313131;
> }
>  
> .has-strong-magenta-color {
>     color: #f78da7;
> }
> ```
>
> The class name is built appending ‘has-‘, followed by the class name
> *using* kebab case and ending with the context name.

Comment: that worked perfectly!